# Geometric visualization of closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In general topology:
Let a ∈ ℝ and ε>0. Opened sphere with a center in a and radius ε is a set

(a+ε, a-ε)={x ∈ ℝ | |x-a|< ε}.

Let it be now A ⊂ ℝ and a ∈ ℝ.

Now I have this statement which I don't understand:

Set $A$ is closed, if set $A^c$ is open.

I would like to ask for help (visualization) and explanation of this statement.

Comment: That's the definition of closed, no?  If not, what definition of  closed are you using?

Comment: Please provide more context on your question. Is $A$ in a metric space, topological space, $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Brief intuition, which someone with the time is welcome to expand into an answer: If $A$ is closed, then intuitively any point "infinitely close" to points of $A$ will also be in $A.$ Therefore, any point not in $A$ (i.e. any point in $A^c)$ will not be "infinitely close" to points  of $A,$ and hence can be surrounded by some (possibly a very tiny) neighborhood that contains no points of $A,$ which intuitively is what $A^c$ being open means (i.e. every point in $A^c$ can be surrounded by a neighborhood that contains only points of $A^c).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closed set is a set that includes its boundary. Consider the real line divided into the following $2$ sets: $A=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x\le 0\}$ and $A^c=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x > 0\}$. The boundary dividing these two sets is the point $x=0$. Which set includes $0$? The set $A$ does. That makes $A$ closed, and $A^c$ open.

Other characterizations of closed and open sets are seen to be equivalent in this example. For instance, an open set is a set in which every point is in the interior. What are points in $A^c$? They are precisely the strictly positive numbers. If we choose any positive number $x$, we can find a neighborhood of $x$, namely the interval $(x-\frac{x}{2},x+\frac{x}{2})$, that is contained entirely in $A^c$. That's not true for $A$, because we could choose the point $0\in A$, and there is no neighborhood of $0$ that is contained entirely in $A$; every neighborhood includes points of both $A$ and $A^c$.

Is this answer addressing your question?

Comment: Definitely! Thank you!